# Django ModelChoiceField is not filled when editing

Tags: django, modelchoicefield

I have ProjectForm form in which one field is ModelChoiceField with foreign key to Company Model. Creating new record and saving is not a problem, but when I want to edit that record this field is empy (like if none company was selected, but in DB I can see it with correct selection), other fields are filled correctly.

I want to avoid changing template code as much as possible so its generated by universal form template.

----- models.py -----

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    ...

class Project(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField()
    ...
```

----- forms.py -----

```
@parsleyfy
class ProjectForm(forms.Form):
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Společnost', queryset=Company.objects.all(), required=False)
    name = forms.CharField(label='Název')
    ...
```

----- view.py -----

```
def edit(request, pk):
    context = {'form_url': reverse('projects:project-edit', args=(pk,)),
               'form_type':'edit'}

    obj = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = ProjectForm(initial=obj.__dict__)
    else:
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                obj.update(**form.cleaned_data)
            except IntegrityError:
                errors = form._errors.setdefault("name", ErrorList())
                errors.append(u"Toto jméno již existuje")
            else:
                return redirect(LIST_URL) # SUCCESSFULLY SAVED

    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, FORM_TEMPLATE, context)
```

----- template.html -----

```
        <form  role="form" action="{{ form_url }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
               data-parsley-validate novalidate>
            {% include 'projects/reusable/form_template.html' %}
        </form>

in which:
    {% elif field|input_type == 'Select' %}
        <div for="{{ field.label }}" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            {{ field.label_tag }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ field|add_classes:'form-control'}}
            {% if field.help_text %}
                <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

----- DB screenshot -----

[image: DB screenshot]

----- Form screenshot ----- (first input is the company)

[image]

Comment: You should use a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) when creating or updating model instances

Comment: I have tried it and I am not comfortable with losing control over field settings

Comment: You can have full control over every field using a ModelForm, what settings do you mean?

Comment: I am just reading [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) and yes, although I was wrong with losing control, its still bit more confusing for me personaly but it might be just a matter of time. I will try to change it if it helps my previous problem

Comment: anyway to reply you... I need to set the following: label, required, choices, label_suffix, initial, min value, help_text and queryset

Comment: `ModelForm(instance=obj)` will provide most `initial` values. You can override labels and help text in the [Meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) or you can actually just set these on the model fields. As for changing required, choices and other arguments, you can define your own fields on the ModelForm and they will override the generated fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initial=obj.__dict__` will return the `project` dict with

```
{
  ...
  company_id: value
}
```

in your form, you defined field name as `company` though. Therefore, you need update your form `initial` with value same as `company_id`, thus the `company` field will be properly populated

```
{
  company: value
}
```

Use `model_to_dict` can explicitly remove non-editable fields, check and get the **ids of foreign keys**, you can read more on its source since is not well documented.

```
def model_to_dict(instance, fields=None, exclude=None):
    """
    Return a dict containing the data in ``instance`` suitable for passing as
    a Form's ``initial`` keyword argument.
    """
    pass


from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

# model_to_dict will handle 'special' fields properly
form = ProjectForm(initial=model_to_dict(obj))
```

Comment: Although it solved my problem I would like to use this opportunity to ask if there is some way, how to avoid this '_id' behavior

Comment: @TomasTrdla you can try `model_to_dict`

Answer (score 0):

As per [@minglyu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10755628/minglyu) answer, I'm adding the code solution

----- forms.py -----

```
@parsleyfy
class ProjectForm(forms.Form):
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Společnost', queryset=Company.objects.all(), required=False)
    name = forms.CharField(label='Název')
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'initial' in kwargs.keys():
            self.initial['company'] = kwargs['initial']['company_id']
```

#### OR

----- views.py -----

```
from django.forms import models
...

def edit(request, pk):
    ...
    obj = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = ProjectForm(initial=models.model_to_dict(obj))
    ...
```